# Adding angular code in script section is not working in jsfiddle

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

Add the following code in html box and it will work as it should be

```
<div ng-app="myapp" data-ng-controller='Ctrl'>
  <h1> Header </h1>
  <h3> {{test}} </h3>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
    app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
        $scope.test = "Hello";
    });
</script>
```

Now move the JavaScript to JavaScript box

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
        $scope.test = "Hello";
});
```

*It start giving error:  Uncaught Error: No module: myapp*

I don't want to write everything in html section, any fix?

Comment: Any chance that you missed to refer that new script file in html?

Comment: By mistake i got the answer while I was clicking here and there, let me add as answer so it can save others time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was playing with setting, found the answer :)

Change the setting Load Type from "OnLoad" to "No wrap - in ", see the attached image.

Strange but it is working like charm :)

[image]